# minimum spacing between button/link and adsense ad unit on mobile site

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

Google states to maintain adequate space between an ad unit and content but does not state how much spacing minimum is required.

On my site, buttons are at least 48 pixels high and at least 48 pixels wide.

We have to assume the majority of users are on mobile and that the width of their screen is under 400 pixels.

What spacing minimum in pixels should I use between an adsense unit on my mobile site and any link (button)?

Comment: I love how Google creates a benchmark/standard/value that you must abide by and then doesn't tell you what that is. It is like saying "Don't go over there." and not pointing or saying where there is.

Comment: If I keep it up, I'll score an award for asking the most useful and unanswerable questions thanks to the big shots who fail to provide proper documentation.

Comment: It all comes down to the beauty in the eye of designer. Few pixels up, few pixels down, and that's it. There's no practice how you can do this. It's based only on your preferences. I mean, maybe there's best practice, but, around 5-10px is good enough for me.

Comment: Perhaps we can recommend something on the big-meta site. Complexity, perplexity, ... ??

Comment: Call me insane, but I'm gonna try a 36 pixel margin for the ad on the mobile site. I wonder if I'll be successful. Maybe I should run a bounty on this question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard and fast rule on how many pixels space you need to place as it varies. The gap needed between an adsense unit and a button will be larger on a mobile device than on a desktop using a mouse and the requirement is that it needs to be of adequate spacing to prevent inadvertent clicks when trying to click the button or link instead.

The only time Google applies a hard and fast rule on the distance from adsense units is how close they can be to flash game content as a user clicking madly in a flash game could easily come out of the games flash viewport and click on the ads inadvertently.

Basically what it boils down to is can you justify how you came up with the distance, can you honestly say you thought about and have come up with 00px for xyz reason. If you can then you should be in the clear. The main thing is that you should not have clickable content right next to the adsense unit as that could be interpreted as trying to trigger a false click.